# Disable an option, on selecting other option in multiselect

Tags: jquery, html, html-select, jquery-ui-multiselect

I have a multiselect in html as shown below. I'm trying to disable all options when **All Types** is selected and disable **All Types** when any other (one or more) options are selected. When the page is loaded, **All Types** option is selected by default, user could change it later. The html looks like:

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="multiselect">
    <option value="default" selected="selected">All Types</option>
    <option value="Mobile">Mobile</option>
    <option value="Laptop">Laptop</option>
    <option value="Desktop">Desktop</option>
</select>
```

And Jquery as:

```
$(".multiselect").multiselect({
    buttonWidth: '150px',
    onChange:function(){
     /*some code needed here*/
    }
});
```

When 'All types' is selected the result should be **['Mobile','Laptop','Desktop']** or **['default']** and if any other option is selected (one or more) then that value in the array. I'm facing some issue with disabling the options on UI. Looking forward for a solution to solve this. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The condition is "if value "default" is selected":

```
if($(this).val() == "default")
```

after that, you just need to disable or enable options, which you can do via normal jQuery.

```
$("option[value='Mobile']").prop("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following change event

```
$('select').on('change',function(){
$(this).find('option').prop("disabled", false);//enable all
if($(this).find('option:selected').is('option[value="default"]')) {}
  $(this).find('option:not(":selected")').prop("disabled", true);
})
```

Comment: I tried this and it throws an error - "ReferenceError: option is not defined"

Comment: That may work for normal select. The question is for Jquery multiselect

Answer (score 0):

for response of madalinivacsu.

if your using chosen-pluggin not forget add trigger :

```
$('[name=option_element]').on('change', function () {
        $(this).find('option').prop("disabled",false).trigger('chosen:updated');//enable all
        if ($(this).find('option:selected').is('option[value="option_default"]')) {
            $(this).find('option:not(":selected")').prop("disabled", true).trigger('chosen:updated');
        }
    });
```